# Inequality $(\sqrt5+2)^x+(\sqrt5-2)^x\le2\sqrt5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> What is the number of all integer solutions to the inequality:
>   $$(\sqrt5+2)^x+(\sqrt5-2)^x\le2\sqrt5$$

I'm pretty clueless to what to do with this one.

This is what I tried:

$(\sqrt5+2)^x+(\sqrt5-2)^x\le2\sqrt5\\(\sqrt5+2)^x\le2\sqrt5-(\sqrt5-2)^x$

then I do $\sqrt[x]{}$ over both sides, to get

$\sqrt5+2\le\sqrt[x]{2\sqrt5-(\sqrt5-2)^x}$

but I'm pretty sure I can't do anything with this.

Second idea I had:

$t=\sqrt5+2\\t^x+(t-4)^x\le2\sqrt5$

but again I think I can't do anything this way.

Comment: As far as I can see, it can be solved to $x=\{-1, 0, 1\}$ by brute force. Verified: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obg9eriqrd

Comment: Yes, and reading from answers it is 3 integers, so that's correct. But there should be a way to solve this without brute-forcing.

Comment: This was not technically brute force. I tested it for $-5 \lt x \lt 5$ and then graphed it. But anyway, checking to see if there is a simple solution without brute-forcing.

Comment: I think that this has another way of solving, since it's coming from a textbook.

Comment: This is a quadratic inequality in $t = (\sqrt5+2)^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$(\sqrt{5}-2)(\sqrt{5}+2)=1$$
So you will get $$(\sqrt{5}-2)^x=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{5}+2)^x}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)$ be the LHS of the inequality.

Since $(\sqrt 5+2)(\sqrt 5-2)=1$, we see that $$f(-x)=f(x)$$

Also since we have
$$(\sqrt 5+2)^2=9+4\sqrt 5\gt 2\sqrt 5$$
we have
$$f(x)\gt 2\sqrt 5$$
for $|x|\ge 2$.

Hence, we have to have $x=\pm 1,0$ and these are sufficient.